Can't open file dialog again after canceling in webview
Opening the dial works and uploading works. However if I cancel/back out of the dialog it won't open again and the page seems to lock up. I only use Android studio about twice a year so I'm not really familiar with handling these kinds of errors;
package com.mobile.popit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.mobile.pop.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUploadMessage;

    WebView mainWebView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

        mainWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.loadUrl("https://domain/Login.php");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == mUploadMessage || intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                return;
            }

            Uri[] result = null;
            String dataString = intent.getDataString();

            if (dataString != null) {
                result = new Uri[]{ Uri.parse(dataString) };
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }


    // ====================
    // Web clients classes
    // ====================

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        // permite la navegacion dentro del webview
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }


    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        // maneja la accion de seleccionar archivos
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

            // asegurar que no existan callbacks
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
            }

            mUploadMessage = filePathCallback;

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*"); // set MIME type to filter

            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

            return true;
        }
    }

}

How can I stop this error and reopen the dialog as well as move to other pages?

I found the solution;
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mUploadMessage == null)
        return;

    mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{});
    mUploadMessage = null;
}


Maybe you can [edit] your answer and explain how the code resolves your problem? I didn't see method onResume() in the code in your question so I assume it is a method you added. Where, exactly did you add it?
